# SendMessageTimeout works from debug environment, but not from installed windows service

Tags: c#, service

When i run the "RespondingWithinMs" (code below) method in my debug environment, it works fine, but when i run it from my installed windows service, it returns false every time meaning it does not get an answer from my application. (Application is started as user SYSTEM, and so is the service). I have tried the process.Responding property, and this works fine. Have also set the timeout to 5000 as the responding property uses, but still not working.

```
const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 2;

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
   HandleRef hWnd,
   int msg,
   IntPtr wParam,
   IntPtr lParam,
   int flags,
   int timeout,
   out IntPtr pdwResult);

   public bool RespondingWithinMs(Process process, int timeoutMs)
   {
       IntPtr ptr2;
       return SendMessageTimeout(
           new HandleRef(process, process.MainWindowHandle),
           0,
           IntPtr.Zero,
           IntPtr.Zero,
           SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
           timeoutMs,
           out ptr2) != IntPtr.Zero;
   }
```